# Is it detrimental to an SMPS to turn it on and off frequently?

Tags: low-power

I've got a 5V SMPS powering two separate servos:

[image]

and

[image]

The smps is a [tps562200](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps562200.pdf)

The application is an autonomous sail boat (3 feet long). One's a winch, the other a rudder. I have code that scans various sensors and when appropriate makes adjustments, anywhere between every 2 seconds and every 30 seconds (depending on how stable things are). The two servos never need to be active at the same time. To not waste power on the switcher's quiescent current, I pull its EN line low whenever not in use.

I'm looking at two possible options:

- disable the switcher in between each servo access
- be a little smarter about it, and keep it enabled during the autopilot cycle

From an power savings standpoint, turning off the switcher more than makes up for the energy lost in recharging the caps on the servos, but does this much cycling do any damage to the switcher / associated circuitry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is mo problem in using the enable lead to turn on and off the SMPS as often as you want to.  In fact, internally, that is how a buck converter works:

[image]

The switch between the supply and the rest of the TPS562200 buck converter is being turned on and off 650,000 times a second.

I have connected up the enable lead of a SMPS boost converter to a PWM output of a LCD controller, thus turning it on and off several times a second, without any issues.

Comment: "I have connected up the enable lead of a SMPS boost converter to a PWWM output of a microcontroller, thus turn it on and off several times a second, without any issues." Haha! Was this experiment for this question, or some other thing? What is the application/use for this? (other than a perfect case in point for this person's question of course)

Comment: Not an experiment, it is being used in a circuit that has gone into production.  Actually the PWM output is coming from an LCD controller, and is being used to boost the voltage up to 15v for the LCD back light.  The on voltage has to remain constant, but the varying duty cycle controls the brightness.

Comment: cool! a neat trick using existing IC capabilities, good job.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Oh damn! I see you have NFETs as low side switches already... I guess my post is not so useful to you. As tcrosley mentions the whole operation of the converter is "ON/OFF" constantly anyway, so if you force it off for longer it will be okay.

MY SUGGESTION WAS:

I highly suggest you just use a spare digital IO line for each, and some P Channel MOSFETs as high side load switches. Let the Switching converter idle with no load, maybe keeping a nice fat 1000-2000uF capacitor charged nearby, before the P FETs. Then when it comes time to turn on the rudder/winch servos, in firmware you should first turn on the high side P FETs and wait 100ms for the power supply to settle just in case, and then continue with your signals/movement.

I have made a fancy schematic diagram for you to explain what I mean. 
[image: schematic diagram of servo power method]

Comment: If you are making adjustments every 2 seconds I would not turn off the regulator so much, rather the load disconnection might be better. What happens if not only are you making adjustments every 2 seconds, but both servos end up on at the same time? You really must be very careful, it's hard to make something autonomous and not also blow itself up.

Comment: can you expand on this a bit? what do you mean by load disconnection vs disabling the reg?

Comment: @kolosy if you disconnect the load/s (the servos) it means the regulator can idle rather than be disabled, which means in theory it should have faster reaction speed (internal circuit does not have to boot up and do all it's logic checks etc) - and with some capacitors on the output there for fast current response It should be good. The capacitors will leak slowly too, but with your 2-30 second expected on/off frequency it's not really an issue.

Comment: gotcha. i'm not worried about reaction time here (the thing is sloshing around in water, a few ms one way or another won't change anything)

Comment: @kolosy your schematic already shows low side N channel FETs used as "enable" for each servo, that achieves the same thing as I'm suggesting, but makes them float rather than disconnect from the power rail

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't hurt the switcher, but are you sure it's worth it? The TPS562200 has an idle current of less than 1mA. Of course the servos also draw some idle current (for example the Hitec HS-785HB sail winch servo draws 8.7mA at 6V). But how much do you really save by switching them off? Is your battery so small that an extra 20mAh would significantly reduce operation time?

When servos are not powered their holding torque is reduced (since it then relies purely on gear-train friction and magnetic cogging in the motor). You may find that the sail arm and/or rudder will not hold position under heavy loading.

Comment: the gearing of the servos is such that it takes a substantial amount of force to move them, so I'm not worried about that. I know I'm going overboard on squeezing out mAs, but I ultimately want this to recharge on solar, so every little bit counts here.